# crontab command not run

Tags: cron

I'm trying to get execute a cron job everyday at noon but i can't get it to run. To test it i even tried something like a simple create command but it never runs, it seems as if the file isn't even used. I also can't see anything going wrong in the log.

```
0 12 * * * mkdir /path/to/folder
```

So is there something wrong with this line or should i look elsewhere?

I created the crontab as root with crontab -e

Comment: cron can only evoke the process if permissions are correct. did you set the permissions correctly

Comment: i didn't change any permissions, what should they be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cron` does not know where to find `mkdir`. So if you do not include a `PATH` in your cron then always use absolute paths. This works:

`0 12 * * * /bin/mkdir /path/to/folder`

Have a look at the part starting with [`using cron`](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) in the link. You can put a path and other variables at the top of `cron` like so:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/
```

That way you have access to `/sbin/`, `/bin/`, `/usr/sbin/` and `/usr/bin/`.

I myself prefer to only include a script in `cron` and set the commands inside that script.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a dumb question, but have you tried a

```
sudo service cron restart
```

after editing? In my case, cron only get changes if I restart it.