# Running command at startup on crontab

Tags: cron

I wanted to run a command on our linux after its done rebooting, I saw that it can be done using crontab. I wanted to run this command

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

on the crontab can i just do:

```
@reboot sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

or do i need to store that in a script?

thank you

Comment: Crontab seems like a wrong tool for restarting eth0. Why not put that command (without sudo) in /etc/rc.local?

Comment: What do you need to do this for?  These tasks are typically done automatically during the boot process, and almost *NEVER* need to be run separately from the automated boot processes...

Comment: @mikewhatever i can't upvote at the moment but just want to thank you for suggesting that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A few notes here before this would work:

1. Don't use `sudo` in a cron job. Instead edit `root`'s crontab instead of your own, e.g. `sudo crontab -e` and then enter commands without `sudo`.
2. As @mikewhatever mentioned, this is an odd use for `cron`, and would likely be better placed in `/etc/rc.local` before the `exit 0` line.
3. If you tell us exactly what you're looking for, we might be able to direct you to a log or config option (restarting your network services at startup feels a little hackish).
4. On most systems `@reboot` should also run after a hard shutdown or crash, but there are different cron implementations so YMMV. I've seen comments in different places asserting both.

**EDIT** (2016/02/17): Removed incorrect blurb on absolute paths; kudos @muru
**EDIT** (2016/10/17): Added shutdown note
**EDIT** (2017/09/11): Revised shutdown note. Not really sure on that one.

Comment: ok just want to clarify, i should just write the full command on `etc/rc.local` without the sudo. so then it will be just 

    ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0 
    exit 0

Comment: `cron` uses the `PATH` given in `/etc/environment`, which does have `/sbin`.

Comment: I did what @mikewhatever suggested and it worked. thank you

Comment: @muru Oh, perhaps I've been laboring on an incorrect assumption; is [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/110503/205638) no longer accurate?

Comment: @TheSchwa Should be. At least since 12.04, `/etc/pam.d/cron` loads `pam_env`, so `/etc/environment` should be read and the default `PATH` set in used. That answer was posted just before 12.04 came out.

Comment: @muru Thanks! Just confirmed that on my own system. I saw that answer on paths a while ago, and just assumed it was correct. Never actually tried making a job without it -.-;

Comment: @TheSchwa The statement that cron's reboot doesn't run on a cold boot is wrong.  Lines with reboot run when the crond daemon starts, period.  That's whether it's a warm boot, cold boot, or whether there was no boot and I just manually shut down crond and started it again.  The crond daemon doesn't know or care why it's being restarted, it will simply run reboot lines whenever it does.

Comment: @KurtFitzner TBF that's not necessarily the case depending on your exact distribution and packages; for example the discuss a file [in this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=635473) that should theoretically prevent restarting the daemon from running reboot jobs. That being said this answer is from a while ago, and I don't recall what testing I did if any at the time.

Comment: There is no `/etc/rc.local` file in Ubuntu 20.04...

Answer (score 7):

You can use crontab for this, but if you use `sudo`, then you will need a `NOPASSWD` rule in `sudoers` to do so. (See [How to run a cron job using the sudo command](https://askubuntu.com/q/173924/158442).)

It would be simpler to edit `/etc/rc.local` and add these commands before the `exit 0` line.

Comment: There is no `/etc/rc.local` file in Ubuntu 20.04...

Comment: @NoopurPhalak create one and make it executable. It will work as usual.