# How can I start automatically a command on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, startup, i3-wm, fish

I have a small command like this

```
xinput set-prop "XP-PEN G430S Pen Pen (0)" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1.155756, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.529, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

to use my XP-PEN tablet, I have to start it automatically every time that I start my PC. How can I do that?

Comment: "startup applications" its available in show all apps.. there you can enter the command..

Comment: I couldn't find it, I'm using i3-gaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `i3` config file for starting up apps.

It's located here: `~/.config/i3/config`

More in official documentation : https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#configuring

Just add these lines:

```
exec --no-startup-id "xinput set-prop 'XP-PEN G430S Pen Pen (0)' --type=float 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 1.155756, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.529, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000"
```

Comment: Ahh, How I couldn't think this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Run `gnome-session-properties` from the command line and add a startup command there. Or alternatively you could use crontab, see:

[Running command at startup on crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/735935/running-command-at-startup-on-crontab)